# Images not appearing in pub/static folder in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

Is there a specific way to make my images appear in the pub static folder?

I have my image uploaded in the `web/images/` directory and when I try and call them in my `phtml` file I am getting a **broken image lin**k.

I manually checked the `pub/static/TestTheme/images` directory and none of my images were being added. This is what I am using in my phtml file.

```
    <img src=”<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/test.png'); ?>” alt="test">
```

Answer (score 2):

Switch to the developer mode, and the static content will be deployed automatically.
Uncomment below line  inside .htaccess of  root folder

```
SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer
```

if still  issue ,use

### command to deploy static files

```
php -f magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

note: right click /bin then select 'Open command window here', before using command, you must have already installed composer in your system.

The developer mode is intended to be used and useful during development.
Particularly, Magento in developer mode shows exceptons on screen instead of showing a generic error message like "There has been an error processing your request".

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the below command.

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Just make sure the followings when you make changes :

- Remove all files under `var/view_preprocessed/`
- Remove all files under `pub/static/`
- Flush Magento Cache `magento cache:flush`

Magento will automatically copy your image to pub/static folder when you reload your page containing the image you want.

Ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/view/static-process.html#static-view-files-url-resolution

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it turned out to be an error in the Less code. The following works:

```
@page__background-image: url("@{baseDir}images/myimage.jpg");

.page-wrapper {
    .lib-css(background-image, @page__background-image);
}
```

Note:

1. Quoting the `url(...)` causes Magento to not pick up the fact that
   my `image.jpg` needs to be copied/linked to `pub/static`.
2. Using single quotes around the filename will cause the file to be copied to `pub/static` but the browser (or at least Safari) will not find the file.